# jQuery Mobile and CSS button

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm moving some old code to jQuery Mobile and have a CSS three colour button, but it seems to conflict with JQM as the design gets messed up.

I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M2eD5/2/) and as you can see that the button looks OK without JQM, but if you tick jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 the text is too low (offset?) and I get a strange black blob on the button.

My button background is like
`background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(255, 255, 255) 33%, rgb(255, 98, 118) 33%, rgb(255, 98, 118) 66%, rgb(121, 178, 203) 66%);`

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve it is to not use a GWT button, but instead use a JQM button and then add the CSS styling in a custom theme.

While JQM does not seem to allow manual line breaks in a button there is a workaround described at [How do I do a manual line break in an jQuery Mobile button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273407/how-do-i-do-a-manual-line-break-in-an-jquery-mobile-button)

Answer (score 1):

The shift of the text and the black blob is the `div` that you put before the `div.html-face`

```
<div class="ui-input-text ui-shadow-inset ui-corner-all ui-btn-shadow ui-body-a">
                <input type="text" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" style="opacity: 0; height: 1px; width: 1px; z-index: -1; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;" class="ui-input-text ui-body-a">
            </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! As I code in GWT and that actually is derived from ToggleButton it will take some work to figure out, but at least now I know where to look.