# How do I do a manual line break in an jQuery Mobile button?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to have a button with multiple lines. I could add `white-space:normal` but that does not allow manual line breaks. I have tried with `<br>` and `&#x00A;` but they don't work as a jQM button is text only.
Note that I do not want automatic line-breaks, but I want to decide myself where to put them.
Nor do I want to change the height of the button. No, I want to add extra linebreaks.

i.e. I want to be able to have a button with
*Text

like

this*
instead of
*Text like this*

Is there a way around this limitation?

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the height of your button? Because that would be a css thing. Can you post some code? Or throw it into a jsFiddle

Comment: I did a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/mMe9B/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there is a way to do it. Since I use GWT I can do

```
JQMButton b = new JQMButton("dummy text");
b.getElement().setInnerHTML("this<br>text<br>works");
```

Answer (score 0):

a couple of ways to do it

1. reduce the width of your button, the text would lay out itself in lines
2. do a shift-enter while typing the text or try a '\n' like this Text \n like \n this

Comment: 1. does not solve the problem since I want manual line breaks 2. does not work